# iPod Reverse Tethering via USB

Tags: ipod, usb, tethering

I want to use my computer's net connection for my iPod Touch via USB cable.

Creating a wireless AP is not an option as I do not want to setup an AP.

iPod Touch - IOS5.x 
Computer - Win7

Bonus - OSX option as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is possible, if your **iPhone** is jailbroken:

(**update**: this does not seem to work for iPod touch, iPads without 3g etc. - because they lack the "second network card" interface)

> can i get it on my ipod touch...?
>   Unfortunately, not.
>   ipod touch doesn't have gprs/edge network interface to redirect it to the proxy.

Follow this lengthy procedure (note that it's originally for iOS 2.x, using a Windows PC):

[SSH to get your iphone online via USB cable](http://alk2blog.blogspot.com/2008/08/ssh-to-get-your-iphone-online-via-usb.html)

> We will connect it to the Internet-connected PC via standard USB cable and get the iphone online in this passthru, reverse mode. Without wifi, without GPRS/EDGE fee to GSM operator. Incredible, impossible? [Read further...](http://alk2blog.blogspot.com/2008/08/ssh-to-get-your-iphone-online-via-usb.html)

- On the PC you will need: Bitvise Tunnelier, itunnel
- And on the iPhone/iPad3G: OpenSSH and a proxy-setting file

---

Alternatively you could try [this procedure](http://xsellize.com/topic/36881-is-it-possible-to-reverse-tether-through-usb/page__view__findpost__p__387312) by dy2k (again only for iDevices supporting Internet Tethering) :

> Reverse Tethering iPhone 3G/3Gs using USB
>
> Step 1: Set up internet tethering on your iPhone.
>
> Step 2: Plug you iPhone into your PC using the provided USB cable.
>
> Step 3: Go to Settings>General>Network>Internet Tethering and switch it to "On." Then it will prompt you for bluetooth or USB, select USB
>
> Step 4: Go to network connections and you should see your LAN connection and a new connection that says "Apple Mobile Device Ethernet." Simply highlight both connections, right click on one and select "Bridge."
>
> You will now be using your PC's internet connection on your iPhone! It works for Cydia App store, Facebook, Safari, ect ect.
>
> Note: After terminating the connection you must delete the bridge and make a new one when you re-connect.

Answer (score 3):

From all my research your request is not possible. Only wireless via internet sharing on your windows 7 machine or the mac.

Answer (score 1):

The iOS software does not look to receive network traffic in from the 30 pin connector, so a major amount of jailbreak work would be needed to accomplish this assuming the hardware has the channels to support "backwards flow" of networking.

Comment: It is possible on the iPhone as it can do internet sharing via USB cable - you then setup a bridge. There is no internet sharing option on the iPod Touch so I can't do that. I don't mind jailbreaking so that is an option.

Comment: The direction in which the flow of internet sharing is one way at present. Phone shares Internet to a computer in a one way relationship. It's like you are asking if a printer can print to a Mac via USB. The direction is wrong in both instances.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible
http://alk2blog.blogspot.sk/2008/08/ssh-to-tether-your-iphone-over-usb.html
Or

http://forums.imore.com/jailbreaking-unlocking-hacks-themes-mods/232233-use-pc-internet-over-iphone-via-usb-cable.html

But needs jailbreak...
Works nice

Comment: Can you explain more about the procedures described in the links you have put in your answer? The answer should be able to stand alone so that others can get an overview of the answer quickly. You should be using links for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to reverse tether my iphone 4s using my ethernet connection through a windows 7 laptop , but not through a Mac Laptop/MacPro . That is quite unsatisfactory for apple users  but still shows that it is possible to use existing ethernet connection to provide internet to Iphone.

Comment: Does not answer the question

Comment: just wanted to share my experience.
user is asking to share laptop internet with ipod touch on windows 7 (or bonus on Osx)

these were the steops 

1. jailbreak iphone 4s (should work also with ipod touch)
2. install TetherMe through cydia
3. connect iphone with USB to laptop.
4. share newly created network adapter in network settings with USB phone (first deactivate the new adapter  then go to propoerties click sharing tab select "allow other users to use this connection" 
5. Run Tetherme - follow the instructions

unfortunately this worked only on Windows Computers