# Internet sharing option "to computers using iPhone USB"

Tags: macos, ios, usb, internet-sharing

Under System Preferences > Sharing, there is an option to share your connection from wherever "to computers using: iPhone USB":

[image: screenshot]

At first glance, this looks to me like:

```
               [Mac]               [iDevice]
-->--(LAN)-->--˄   ˅-->--(USB)-->--˄
```

i.e. reverse tethering over USB.
However, according to [these](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104991) [two](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/44401) answers, reverse tethering is not possible over USB with a vanilla iOS.
[Three](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/42245) [other](https://redd.it/3tvki0) [sources](http://alk2blog.blogspot.ch/2008/08/ssh-to-get-your-iphone-online-via-usb.html) describe a way to do it on a jailbroken iOS, but although stated otherwise, this seems to work only with a Windows PC.

Also, I'm pretty sure that the above option is **neither** "normal" tethering, like

```
                  [iDevice]               [Mac]
-->--(Mobile)-->--˄       ˅-->--(USB)-->--˄
```

which would be under "Network":

[image: screenshot]

**nor** sharing a connection from an iDevice to something else, like

```
                  [iDevice]               [Mac]               [Whatever]
-->--(Mobile)-->--˄       ˅-->--(USB)-->--˄   ˅-->--(USB)-->--˄
```

which would be in the "from" field on internet sharing:

[image: screenshot]

So, about the option shown in the first picture:
Evidently it cannot be used to tether to vanilla iDevices, and there's no way Apple would put it there for jailbroken devices, on which it *also* doesn't seem to work.

So what does it actually do, and what can it be used for?

Answer (score 1):

I believe in Internet Sharing settings, OS X is just listing all of the network interfaces. iPhone USB is listed there for that reason, even though it's not a meaningful option.

Comment: I have to admit, I didn't think about that... doesn't sound like Apple, but now that you mention it...

Comment: Well, the dialog is just iterating over the list of interfaces…